# Force Default Initialized Constructor in POD?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to force the default initialized constructor to be used for a POD type. So that all the values such as integers as initialized to zero?

```
struct MyPod
{
    int a; // whether a is initialized to zero is dependent on creation method
};

struct MyOtherNonPod
{
    int b;
    MyOtherNonPod() : b(0) // b initialized to zero regardless of creation method
    {}
};

MyPod* pod = new MyPod; // pod->a not initialized
MyOhterNonPod* otherPod = new MyOtherNonPod; // otherPod->b is initialized to zero
```

Is there a way to do this without having to define a constructor and manually initalize all the varaibles? But instead just enforce the default initialized constructor to always be called?

```
MyPod* pod = new MyPod{}; // pod->a is default initialized to zero
```

Is there a way to force the above constructor to be used regardless of whether the `{}` are there or not? I have a lot of variables in my POD class with verbose names, i'd rather eliminate the uncertainty that the class won't be initialized to zero depending on whether i default initialize or not. Without having to manually set them all.

Comment: `MyOtherPod` has a user-specified constructor and so is not a POD object. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf

Comment: See also: http://ideone.com/zzgItk

Comment: An option is `struct MyPodV: MyPod { MyPodV(): MyPod() {} };` . The `MyPodV` is not a POD, but the base class is, so that might suit your requirements.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes that's probably the best solution i've seen, thanks! If you post it as an answer, i'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do what you requested, because POD may not have user-declared constructor. One alternative is to make a class that has the POD as base class:

```
struct MyPodV : MyPod
{
    MyPodV: MyPod() {}
};
```

Then you can create MyPodV objects, and still use them with functions that expect `MyPod`.

Of course there is the problem that you might forget and make a `MyPod` instead of a `MyPodV`, so this doesn't really gain much over requiring people to do `MyPod x{}`.  Perhaps you could use a naming convention to make it harder to accidentally create the POD on its own though.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a POD is that no user-defined constructor can be there and all the members must be POD.

So, no you can't. But it looks like you don't need a POD.

```
#include <iostream>

struct NonPOD {
    int    i = {};
    double d = {};
    // NonPOD() = default;
};

int main() {
    NonPOD x;
    std::cout << x.i << ", " << x.d << "\n";
}
```

Comment: According to [cppr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) this is not an aggregate. Nvm, it is in C++ 14, just not in C++11.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without adding the `= {}` ?

Comment: The standard does not say "user defined" it says "non-trivial". `struct NonTrivial { NonTrivial(); }; struct Trivial { Trivial() {} };`

Comment: @kfsone Mmm. Yeah I was hopping on two thoughts while writing that answer. Anyways, for true PODs we can't have what the OP wants.

Comment: @Sehe actually, I take that back - the standard says `A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if` so - it can't be user provided at all.

Comment: Wait, now it's about destructors? I'm pretty sure a defaulted or empty destructor is still trivial as long as all base classes and members are. I think we're getting a bit far from the question here :)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no default auto initialization in c++ at least not in the way you are expecting it.

As far as I know you have exactly three options to choose from, at least since the c++11 standard:

1. Add a default constructor to each of your structs, which can be a bit tedious.

   ```
   //Init by default constructor
   struct POD3{
       int a;
       int b;
       char c;
       POD3(): a{}, b{}, c{} {};
   };
   POD3 stackPod3;
   POD3* heapPod3 = new POD3;
   ```
2. Add a default initialization for each member of your structs, this is what I would do.

   ```
   //Init by field
   struct POD{
       int a{};
       int b{};
       char c{};        
   };
   POD stackPod;
   POD* heapPod = new POD;
   ```
3. Or take the risk and be dependent on the correct syntax when creating your objects, that's the worst choice.

   ```
   //Init by object creation
   struct POD2{
       int a;
       int b;
       char c;        
   };
   POD2 stackPod2{};
   POD2* heapPod2 = new POD2{};
   ```

As already mentioned above my personal opinion is that the second option is best for code readability and the chance of missing a member is quite low.

Comment: the fist one isn't a pod.

Comment: @RussellGreene neither is the second: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74083e9916751883

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to do it in C++11. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyPod
{
    int a; // whether a is initialized to zero is dependent on creation method
};


int main()
{
    MyPod* pod = new MyPod{ 23 }; // pod->a initalized to 23

}
```

It is necessary to use the curly braces in this case, because what this is doing is initalizing each member sequentially. If you had more types in `MyPod` then it might look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyPod
{
    int a; 
    bool b;
    double c;
};


int main()
{
    MyPod* pod = new MyPod{ 23, false, 32.93 }; 
}
```

Comment: I want it to be default initialized though (to zero) without having to rely on how it is initialized. I want it to be zero initialized without having to rely on which method is used to initialize it without having to manually set every variable to zero.